# pandas dataframe index access not raising an exception when out of bounds?

Tags: pandas

How can the following MWE script work? I actually want the assignment (right before the print) to fail. Instead it changes nothing and raises no exception. This is some of the weirdest behaviour.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l = ['a', 'b']
d = np.array([[False]*len(l)]*3)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=l, data=d, index=range(1,4))
df["a"][4] = True
print df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say `df["a"][4] = True`, you are modifying the `a` series object, and you aren't really modifying the `df` DataFrame because `df`'s index does not have an entry of 4.  I wrote up a snippet of code exhibiting this behavior:

In [90]:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
l = ['a', 'b']
d = np.array([[False]*len(l)]*3)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=l, data=d, index=range(1,4))
df['a'][4] = True

print "DataFrame:"
print df

DataFrame:
       a      b
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
```

In [91]:

```
df['b'][4]=False
print "DataFrame:"
print df

DataFrame:
       a      b
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
```

In [92]:

```
print "DF's Index"
print df.index

DF's Index
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')
```

In [93]:

```
print "Series object a:" 
print df['a']

Series object a:
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

In [94]:

```
print "Series object b:" 
print df['b']

Series object b:
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In a nutshell underlying it is a dict. Hmmm. Is there any way to do assignment with key checking? That is other than `if key in df.index`. Would prefer something that raises an exception.